# Pearson Correlation as a Loss Function

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, pearson-correlation

I'm training a TF Feed Forward network where my goal is to produce predictions from 0 to 1 that are as close as possible to the target scores. A single training instance consists of around 450 features and there are circa 1500 examples in the dataset. I use 4 layers in my network each with a Relu activation and then the final 'out' layer has a sigmoid activation. When I use MSE as the loss function, I get decent (but not optimal) results. I have tried to use the following as a loss function:

```
# Define loss and optimizer
#pearson correlation as loss function
length = 443

#apply regularization (l2)
Beta = 0.01
regularizer = tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['h1']) +   
tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['h2']) + tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['h3']) + 
tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['h4'])

#used to report correlation 
pearson = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation(intensity, 
Y, name="pearson")


#pearson corr. as loss?
# multiply by -1 to maximize correlation i.e. minimize negative 
correlation 
original_loss = -1 * length * tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(intensity, Y)) 
- (tf.reduce_sum(intensity) * tf.reduce_sum(Y))
divisor = tf.sqrt(
        (length * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(intensity)) - 
tf.square(tf.reduce_sum(intensity)))) *\
        tf.sqrt(
        length * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Y)) - 
tf.square(tf.reduce_sum(Y)))

 loss_op = tf.truediv(original_loss, divisor)
 loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(loss_op + Beta * regularizer)
#Init optimizer
 optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, 
 epsilon = 1e-09)
 train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)
```

The idea is to minimise negative correlation, i.e. maximise positive correlation. However, after a lot of experimentation with the hyperparameters, this still gives me 'nan' error and reports 'nan' Pearson correlation. Any ideas as to why that could be?

Comment: why u use *\ this operator?

Comment: This just splits the line, has no effect.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you bet getter results optimizing with pearson r?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation()` returns a tuple `(pearson_r, update_op)`, so in principle you should be able to feed the update_op directly into `optimizer.minimize()`.